# IE9 throwing error on jQuery.ajax "done" method

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I've got code working in the latest Chrome and Firefox.
IE9 however hates me (and I feel the same).

The specific error I'm getting is:
`Object doesn't support property or method 'done'`

The code in question:

```
app.$.ajax({
                url: app.baseUrl + "Geos",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function (data) {
                app.controls.ddlGeos.html('');

                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    var geo = data.d[i];
                    var option = $(document.createElement("option"));

                    option.attr('value', geo.code);
                    option.html(geo.name);

                    app.controls.ddlGeos.append(option);
                };
            }).fail(function (xhr, status) {
                console.log("Error retrieving Geo list", xhr, status);
            }).always(function (data, status, xhr) {
                app.controls.ddlGeos.parent().find('#geo_ajax_image').remove();
                app.setSelectedValues(app.controls.ddlGeos, app.controls.hdnGeo.val());
            });
```

Something that makes this slightly abnormal is that I am manually loading the latest version of jQuery 1.8.2) like this:

```
// The following code allows us to run jQuery 1.8.2 independantly of the main jQuery
    if (!jq) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js';
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
            window.jq18 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
            app.init(window.jq18);
        };
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    } else {
        app.init(jq);
    }
```

The reason I am doing this is because I'm writing against a very old web app and I can't overwrite window.$ so I'm sending my app the newest jQuery version.
However, I have done some console logging and the correct version of jQuery IS being loaded by the time the ajax call has been hit.  `app.$().jquery` outputs `"1.8.2"`

**EDIT**
Ok, I think I know part of the problem.  I'm doing similar code in 2 different ASP.Net UserControls (think encapsulated web page).  They BOTH are loading jQuery 1.8.2 this way because neither can be sure the other exists.  It seems like Firefox and Chrome handle this ok, but IE is somehow causing my "onreadystatechange" event to fire twice (and somehow one of them is happening without the proper version of jquery).
Is there anything I can do to modify that jquery loading code to ensure it only happens once?  I'm calling it like this:

```
(function (jq) {
    // All my "app" code here
    app = {
        init : function($) {
            app.$ = $ || window.$;
            // Other code
        }
    };

    if (!jq) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js';
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
            window.jq18 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
            app.init(window.jq18);
        };
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    } else {
        app.init(jq);
    }
})(window.jq18);
```

Comment: Use **.success** not **.done**

Comment: @VIDesignz: No, `.success` is the deprecated version of `.done`.

Comment: Ohhh, thats news to me!  Thanks for enlightening me!

Comment: @James P. Wright: What does the `$.ajax` call actually return?

Comment: @pimvdb : give me a few minutes while I figure out how to debug properly in IE.  Been a while.

Comment: @pimvdb : console.log on it says: "[object XMLHTTPRequest]"

Comment: @James P. Wright: Sounds like that's the native xhr and not the jQuery one. Can you show a demo on http://jsfiddle.net? It sounds like a jQuery bug if that's true.

Comment: @pimvdb : check the edited question.  Looks like I'm causing my "app" to init twice in IE (but not in Chrome/Firefox)

Comment: Well, you effectively have two event handlers and IE apparently likes to fire both. I guess `onload` is enough.

Comment: @pimvdb : Which is, I suppose, technically correct what IE is doing.  I am assigning the script.onload and the jquery "onreadystatechange" event to the same function.  I wonder why Chrome and Firefox only fire one of the events.  Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it (it fixed the issue to just use "script.onload".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 seems to have `readyState`s such as `"uninitialized"`, `"loading"` and `"complete"`. The transitions between these seem to fire `onreadystatechange` in IE. The `onload` is eventually *also* fied, so you're initializing everything several times. I'm not sure how that causes the weird return value of `$.ajax`, but apparently removing it fixes it.

Comment: What was happening was that the second time IE was calling the function assigned to "onload" and "onreadystatechange" it was passing in nothing, which caused the app to default to window.$ (which is jQuery 1.4 and doesn't have a .done() method on .ajax)